# Pc monitor gets fuzzy

Tags: display, power-supply

After replacing the heatsink and power supply, the monitor got very fuzzy and grainy.

I have changed the cable and even replaced the monitor but the issue remained. It seems that the  monitor is ok and it has something to do with the PC itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: On board or external GPU?

Comment: What's the monitor's native resolution and is that what Windows is set to use?

Comment: Hi Dave, it is on board integrated intel GPU and the resolution is 1600*900 and it is the default monitor

Comment: i have updated the the the GPU and and the problem remains and conncected and disconnected the cable and nothing happened

Comment: Some old Intel GPUs do not support widescreen resolutions, let us know the exact model. You can find that info in Device Manager and then under Display Adapters

Comment: intel G41 express chipset